# compute row-wise summary statistics such as mean, max, min across columns sharing similar names using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

When analyzing data using R, I need to compute row-wise summary statistics (mean, min, max, standard deviation) for columns that have similar names (e.g., the same prefix). While I can achieve it using package such as matrixStats, I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do it using dplyr. Attached below is the code for generating a sample dataset and my solution for computing the row-wise summary statistics. Thanks!

```
######SAMPEL CODE#####
library("tidyverse")
library("matrixStats")

# create a sample dataset
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 6))
names(sample_data) <- c("ID", "score_1", "score_2", "score_3", "score_4", "score_5")
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(ID = seq(1:10),
         score_1 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_2 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_3 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_4 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_5 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)))

score_columns <- grep("score_", names(sample_data))

sample_data <- sample_data %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("score_")), na.rm = TRUE),
         max_score = rowMaxs(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE),
         sd_score = rowSds(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate these statistics 'by row' using dplyr [row-wise operations](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html) combined with the [c_across function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/c_across.html), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(matrixStats)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'matrixStats'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     count

# create a sample dataset
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 6))
names(sample_data) <- c("ID", "score_1", "score_2", "score_3", "score_4", "score_5")
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(ID = seq(1:10),
         score_1 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_2 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_3 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_4 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_5 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)))

score_columns <- grep("score_", names(sample_data))

output <- sample_data %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("score_")), na.rm = TRUE),
         max_score = rowMaxs(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE),
         sd_score = rowSds(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE)) 
output
#>    ID score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5 mean_score max_score  sd_score
#> 1   1       1       5       4       3       2        3.0         5 1.5811388
#> 2   2       3       5       1       5       2        3.2         5 1.7888544
#> 3   3       2       5       3       2       4        3.2         5 1.3038405
#> 4   4       3       4       3       3       5        3.6         5 0.8944272
#> 5   5       2       3       2       2       3        2.4         3 0.5477226
#> 6   6       4       2       4       3       2        3.0         4 1.0000000
#> 7   7       2       2       1       3       1        1.8         3 0.8366600
#> 8   8       3       4       1       3       4        3.0         4 1.2247449
#> 9   9       3       2       3       4       2        2.8         4 0.8366600
#> 10 10       5       2       3       3       4        3.4         5 1.1401754

output2 <- sample_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mean_score = mean(c_across(starts_with("score_"))),
         max_score = max(c_across(!!score_columns)),
         sd_score = sd(c_across(!!score_columns)))
output2
#> # A tibble: 10 × 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       ID score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5 mean_score max_score sd_score
#>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1       1       5       4       3       2        3           5    1.58 
#>  2     2       3       5       1       5       2        3.2         5    1.79 
#>  3     3       2       5       3       2       4        3.2         5    1.30 
#>  4     4       3       4       3       3       5        3.6         5    0.894
#>  5     5       2       3       2       2       3        2.4         3    0.548
#>  6     6       4       2       4       3       2        3           4    1    
#>  7     7       2       2       1       3       1        1.8         3    0.837
#>  8     8       3       4       1       3       4        3           4    1.22 
#>  9     9       3       2       3       4       2        2.8         4    0.837
#> 10    10       5       2       3       3       4        3.4         5    1.14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As this is a dplyr-specific solution, you can incorporate further data manipulations (e.g. `filter()` to select specific rows) where other solutions will fail or require awkward workarounds, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(matrixStats)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'matrixStats'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     count

# create a sample dataset
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 6))
names(sample_data) <- c("ID", "score_1", "score_2", "score_3", "score_4", "score_5")
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(ID = seq(1:10),
         score_1 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_2 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_3 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_4 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_5 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)))

score_columns <- grep("score_", names(sample_data))

output <- sample_data %>%
  filter(ID < 6) %>%
  mutate(mean_score = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("score_")), na.rm = TRUE),
         max_score = rowMaxs(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE),
         sd_score = rowSds(as.matrix(sample_data[,c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE)) 
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `max_score`.
#> ℹ `max_score = rowMaxs(as.matrix(sample_data[, c(score_columns)]), na.rm = TRUE)`.
#> ℹ `max_score` must be size 5 or 1, not 10.


output2 <- sample_data %>%
  filter(ID < 6) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mean_score = mean(c_across(starts_with("score_"))),
         max_score = max(c_across(!!score_columns)),
         sd_score = sd(c_across(!!score_columns)))
output2
#> # A tibble: 5 × 9
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      ID score_1 score_2 score_3 score_4 score_5 mean_score max_score sd_score
#>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1       5       2       5       5       1        3.6         5     1.95
#> 2     2       1       2       4       1       2        2           4     1.22
#> 3     3       1       2       2       4       5        2.8         5     1.64
#> 4     4       5       4       3       3       5        4           5     1   
#> 5     5       4       2       2       5       4        3.4         5     1.34
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way I used to answer your question:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("matrixStats")

# create a sample dataset
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 6))
names(sample_data) <- c("ID", "score_1", "score_2", "score_3", "score_4", "score_5")
sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(ID = seq(1:10),
         score_1 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_2 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_3 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_4 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)),
         score_5 = round(runif(10, 1, 5)))

score_columns <- colnames(sample_data)[grep("score_", names(sample_data))]

sample_data<- sample_data %>% 
  rowwise(ID) %>% 
  mutate(mean_score = mean(c_across(score_columns[1]:length(score_columns))),
         max_score = max(c_across(score_columns[1]:length(score_columns))),
         sd_score = sd(c_across(score_columns[1]:length(score_columns))))
```

If you want an even easier way using base functions, try the following:

```
score_columns <- grep("score_", names(sample_data))
sample_data['mean_score'] <- apply(sample_data[,score_columns], 1, mean)
sample_data['max_score'] <- apply(sample_data[,score_columns], 1, max)
sample_data['sd_score'] <- apply(sample_data[,score_columns], 1, sd)
```

Comment: Your dplyr solution works with this example but fails if the "score" columns are not consecutive e.g.  with columns `c("ID", "score_1", "dont_include_1", "score_2", "dont_include_2", "score_3", "dont_include_3", "score_4", "dont_include_4", "score_5", "dont_include_5")` the mean/sd will be incorrect.